# Char $p$ representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ and $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

It is a well known fact that the irreducible representations of $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F_p}}$ are given by the symmetric powers $Symm^k(V)$, where $V = \overline{\mathbb{F}_p}^2$, for $k$ ranging in $0,\ldots,p-1$. In the case of $GL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ irreducible representations are exhausted by:

$$\sigma_{k,n} = Symm^k(V) \otimes det^n$$

> My question is then if there is a systematic way to know which of these irreducible representations appear in higher symmetric powers ($k>p-1$), either for $SL_2$ or $GL_2$?

And what about tensor products $Symm^k(V) \otimes Symm^l(V)$?

Comment: Steinberg's tensor product theorem?

Comment: Section 5.4 of Kleidman & Liebeck should shed light on this question. They deal with all finite groups of Lie type, and also explain Steinberg's tensor product theorem, as per the comment of @wccanard. I don't know whether STPT quite answers your question as it gives a decomposition by tensors (as the name suggests), and I'm not sure if that's what you mean when you say "which of these *appear*". Still, it's a good first place to look. If you need an e-copy email me.

Comment: Off-topic: One hour later I just understood the pun in the moniker @wccanard. I like it!

Comment: @wccanard: Steinberg's tensor product theorem only becomes relevant for the groups over larger finite fields than the prime field (and in this rank 1 case actually goes back to much earlier work of Brauer-Nesbitt).   

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer to your basic question is no; but a lot is known (and written down in various places including a 1978 paper in J. Algebra by D.J. Glover based on his A.N.U. thesis).   The long answer is that the bookkeeping involved even for this small case gets quite involved, a little more so for the finite general linear groups than for the special linear groups.

There is a detailed survey with references in Chapter 19 of my 2006 LMS Lecture Note Series 326 *Modular Representations of Finite Groups of Lie Type* (Cambridge U. Press).   The emphasis throughout is on the "defining" characteristic $p$.   In Chapter 19 the main theme is the decomposition of all symmetric powers of the natural representation for general or special linear groups of any rank, specialized to rank 1 in 19.7.

Even in the rank 1 case it's unreasonable to expect explicit closed formulas, but the fact that weight multiplicities are 1 already simplifies the problem a lot.  A nontrivial test case involves the multiplicity of the trivial representation in each space of homogeneous polynomials in two indeterminates: this leads to the *Dickson invariants* (for the finite groups over arbitrary finite fields).  But this already requires a lot of ingenuity.  As far as I know, the approaches described in this chapter are the only ones so far attempted.

Concerning your added question about tensoring two symmetric powers, this must get a lot more complicated to work out in detail.   Since representations in prime characteristic generally fail to be completely reducible, you start to run into a large assortment of indecomposable modules including the projective ones.   But if you are only asking for composition factor multiplicities, there is a better chance of obtaining these (in principle) from study of the individual symmetric powers.

It's important here to take a close look at what has already been done, since the results go back all the way to older work of Dickson and involve quite a range of methods in the modular representation theory of finite groups.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The kind of description that appears in the paper of Glover seems to be enough for the cases I needed. 